# cosine similarity for multiple column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, cosine-similarity

```
id  size    numberOfPlants  balcony   available  publicTransport    
0   1191    3               0         1           1
1   3251    2               1         0           0
2   1641    1               1         1           0
3   2133    3               0         0           1
```

I have a dataset with multiple column values where each row represents one object. I want to calculate cosine similarity between all rows such that I consider all factors, size, numberOfPlants, balcony (boolean), available (boolean), and publicTransport (boolean) with an equal weightage. If I enter a `id`, I want to get back an `id` of the row which seems the most similar. How can I calculate cosine similarity here?

Comment: Could you share a larger sample of your dataset? It would help to help you. Also, which combinations are you desiring to do this on?

Comment: what do you mean by combinations? I want to check for similarity in all size, numberOfPlants, balcony, available, and publicTransport. But collectively not individually @SergedeGossondeVarennes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [cosine_similarity](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) from sklearn. Where a `target` is any row for which you want to find similar. It would also be better to exclude `id` from the comparison.

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np

def get_similar_row(rows, target):
    """Return the index of the most similar row"""
    return np.argmax(cosine_similarity(rows, [target]))


get_similar_row([[1191, 3, 0, 1, 1], 
                 [3251, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
                 [1641, 1, 1, 1, 0]], [2133, 3, 0, 0, 1], top_n=2)
```

The output will be: `1`

If you need to get `top n` similar rows:

```
def get_top_n_similar_rows(rows, target, top_n=1):
    """Return the top n indices of the most similar rows"""
    return cosine_similarity(rows, [target]).reshape(1, -1)[0].argsort()[::-1][:top_n]
```

Comment: how can I pass rows into it exactly? Is this supposed to return the index of the most similar one?

Comment: what will be the format for rows/target? What really is the target here?

Comment: Yes, the function returns the index of the most similar row. I updated the answer. Hopefully, now it is clearer now.

Comment: Is there any other way where we can get like top 3 most similar items? Instead of just one?

Comment: I added a separate function to get the first n similar rows.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick for pairwise cosine similarities (Here I assume you've delt with potential NaN):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
similarity = cosine_similarity(df)
print(similarity)
```

Example df:

```
   id  size  numberOfPlants  balcony  available  publicTransport
0   1     3               1        0          1                1
1  23     4               2        4          0                2
2   3     5               2        5          1                3
3   4     6               2       76          3                4
4   5     7              34        4          4                5
5   6     8               5        2          5                6
6   4     4               6        1          6                4
```

Then the above code returns

```
[[1.         0.45345772 0.77907297 0.11234465 0.53344315 0.92557018
  0.80683665]
 [0.45345772 1.         0.5838878  0.23664101 0.276951   0.60827093
  0.50306617]
 [0.77907297 0.5838878  1.         0.67443414 0.51221106 0.85759678
  0.71288699]
 [0.11234465 0.23664101 0.67443414 1.         0.16973016 0.25879044
  0.19243529]
 [0.53344315 0.276951   0.51221106 0.16973016 1.         0.63498516
  0.76022001]
 [0.92557018 0.60827093 0.85759678 0.25879044 0.63498516 1.
  0.93652389]
 [0.80683665 0.50306617 0.71288699 0.19243529 0.76022001 0.93652389
  1.        ]]
```

Comment: How can I use this to get the most similar row by inputting an id?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the id be excluded from the similarity calculation?